# Plotting gradient approximation of a function

Tags: julia, gradient

I am attempting to graph the local approximation of a function using the gradient. Here is my code:

```
using Random
using LinearAlgebra
using Plots
using LaTeXStrings

Random.seed!(0)
x = rand(5,1)
v = rand(5,1)
alphas = LinRange(-1,1,100)

f(x) = log(sum(exp.(x)))
∇f(x) = (1/log(sum(exp.(x))))*[exp(x[1]),exp(x[2]),exp(x[3]), 
                               exp(x[4]), exp(x[5])]

plot(alphas, [f(x+alpha*v) for alpha in alphas], color = :black,
label = L"f(x + \alpha v)")
plot!(alphas, [f(x) + alpha*dot(∇f(x), v) for alpha in alphas], 
    color=:red, label=L"f(x) + \alpha \nabla f(x)^T v")
xlabel!(L"\alpha")
```

[image: Gradient]

From my understanding, the red line should be tangent to the curve at `alpha = 0`, however this is not the case. I am hoping to identify whether this is an issue with my calculation of the gradient, or if it is something incorrect I did in Julia.

The function in question is f(x) = log(Σe^x_i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an incorrect formula for `∇f(x)`. It should be:

```
∇f(x) = (ex = exp.(x); ex / sum(ex)) # precalculate exp.(x) to avoid computing it twice
```

You could have also avoided calculating it manually by e.g. using the ForwardDiff.jl package and writing:

```
∇f(x) = ForwardDiff.gradient(f, x)
```

Comment: Thank you! If you don't mind elaborating, what precisely was wrong with my formula for the gradient?

Comment: You had `log` in the denominator, while the derivative of `log(x)` is just `1/x` not `1/log(x)`.